# Multi-line text values destroy the horizontal alignment of the layout

Tags: html, css, html-email, responsive

In the following code, when the value of the first column exceeds one line (in this case the item with the title "*a long value that exceeds one line*"), the column is no longer aligned with the other two:
[image]

```html
<table>
      <tr >
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 17px 19px 0; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;" >
          <table border="0" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:0 !important;" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding: 17px 0 0;">
                <h2 style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Playfair Display', Georgia, serif; font-style: italic; font-size: 25px; color: #E35E19; font-weight: 900;">Coming soon</h2>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- 3 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 0 19px 17px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">
          <table border="0" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:0 !important;">
            <tr>
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">a long value that exceeds one line</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I have stripped the code off of the unnecessary tags. The code as seen above sits in a separate file and is currently not a contained snippet.

Comment: You really should split the `CSS` from the `HTML` using classes. That would make the code much easier to handle. Also, the snippet works fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: @kabanus the developer has both used CSS separately at the beginning of the email and within the HTML tags. I wanted the code as close to the original as possible.

Comment: No problem, just a general suggestion to anyone reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put another `valign='top'` in the nested table:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t6uwdczh/1/)

```
...
<tr valign='top'>
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
...
```

Full code:

```
<table>
      <tr >
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 17px 19px 0; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;" >
          <table border="0" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:0 !important;" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding: 17px 0 0;">
                <h2 style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Playfair Display', Georgia, serif; font-style: italic; font-size: 25px; color: #E35E19; font-weight: 900;">Coming soon</h2>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- 3 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 0 19px 17px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">
          <table border="0" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:0 !important;">
            <tr valign='top'>
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">a long value that exceeds one line</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: thank you so much. not a front-end person and this had kept me up all night. have a fantastic day!

Answer (score 3):

The default vertical alignment is center, but you want top:

```css
tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr >
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 17px 19px 0; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;" >
          <table border="0" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:0 !important;" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding: 17px 0 0;">
                <h2 style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Playfair Display', Georgia, serif; font-style: italic; font-size: 25px; color: #E35E19; font-weight: 900;">Coming soon</h2>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- 3 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 0 19px 17px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">
          <table border="0" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:0 !important;">
            <tr>
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">a long value that exceeds one line</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
              <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
              <td width="33.33%">
                <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center" >
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" height="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td  style="line-height: 20px; color: #000000; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                      <p style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px;"><i>Lorem ipsum</i></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <!-- Column : END -->
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: true. but this would make for all `<tr>` tags, am I right. otherwise, you are spot on. sorry, i had to select the other answer. thanks for you time anyway.